# How to determine file URL from DVTSourceTextView

Tags: plugins, xcode7

I’m writing a plugin to Xcode 7. I have the DVTSourceTextView and can manipulate it just fine. One of the things I want to find is which file is related to this. Unfortunately, DVTSourceTextView doesn’t appear to offer that information - or if it does, it is buried in a way I fail to see.

I’m sure it is rather trivial, I’m just missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was easier than I thought it was. I was approaching it from a different (although almost correct) way.

```
class func currentEditorView() -> (NSURL?, NSView?) {
    let currentWindowController = NSApp.keyWindow?.windowController
    guard currentWindowController!.className == "IDEWorkspaceWindowController" else { return (nil, nil) }

    let filename = currentWindowController!.valueForKey("editorArea")!.valueForKey("lastActiveEditorContext")!.valueForKey("originalRequestedDocumentURL")

    let editor = currentWindowController!.valueForKey("editorArea")!.valueForKey("lastActiveEditorContext")!.valueForKey("editor")!.valueForKey("textView")

    return (filename as? NSURL, editor as? NSView)
}
```

This gives me both the filename as an NSURL as well as the DVTSourceTextView as an NSView without the need of including private headers. Spiffy.

Now not only do I know the name of the file I’m editing, but I can also determine if it is a swift, objc, c or c++ file! THAT is coolness!